# What is the primary decomposition of $Z/70Z \times Z/100Z \times Z/49Z \times Z/40Z$? Its invariant elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, invariant-theory

Is the following the right way to do?

Let $G = Z/70Z \times Z/100Z \times Z/49Z \times Z/40Z$

Then its primary decomposition yields to :
$$Z/(7 * 2* 5)Z \times Z/(5^2 * 2^2)Z \times Z/(7^2)Z \times Z/(2^3 * 5)Z $$
So:
$$G(2)=Z/2Z \times Z/4Z \times Z/8Z$$
$$G(5)=Z/5Z \times Z/5Z \times Z/25Z$$
$$G(7)=Z/7Z \times Z/49Z$$

And $G \simeq G(2) \times G(5) \times G(7)$

ie $G \simeq Z/10Z \times Z/140Z \times Z/9800Z$

So the invariant factors of $G$ are 2, 140 and 9800.

Comment: $G(5)=\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/25\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The systematic method to convert a primary decomposition into an invariant factor decomposition is to list the powers of each prime in increasing order right justified and multiply them vertically (using the Chinese Remainder Theorem):
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 4 & 8 \\
5 & 5 & 25 \\
  & 7 & 49 \\
\hline
10 & 140 & 9800 \\
\end{array}
This coincides with your answer.

Comment: Thanks, and if there was 2 times the same number would that still holds? Like if $G(2)=\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z  \times \Bbb Z/8 \Bbb Z$ ?

Comment: @astudentofmaths, yes, it already happens with $5$ in the second line.